# How to call the menu objects from another class?

Tags: java, android, menu

These are codes, how to pass the menu object from one class to another? 
What's wrong with my code?

This is my MainActivity class.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    String msg = " ";
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_settings:
            msg = "Settings";
            break;
        case R.id.action_report:
            msg= "Report";
            break;
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, msg + "Checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This is my SecondActivity class

```
public class Income extends AppCompatActivity{

View_Expenses v = new View_Expenses();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            v.onCreateOptionsMenu(R.menu.main_menu); //Here have problem
}
```

Comment: Why are you instantiating the `View_Expenses` directly? Can you also post your stack trace?

Comment: `onCreateOptionsMenu` belongs to AppCompatActivity class and it can be overriden by any class that extends it. You can't call it anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the same code you used in the first activity in the second one,

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

not the code you tried in `onCreate`. If you want the menu item responses to be the same, copy the `onOptionsItemSelected` method too.